# awk to compare two file by identifier & output in a specific format

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, gawk

I have 2 large files i need to compare all pipe delimited

file 1

```
a||d||f||a
1||2||3||4
```

file 2

```
a||d||f||a
1||1||3||4
1||2||r||f
```

Now I want to compare the files & print accordingly such as if any update found in file 2 will be printed as `updated_value#oldvalue` & any new line added to file 2 will also be updated accordingly.

So the desired output is: (only the updated & new data)

```
1||1#2||3||4
1||2||r||f
```

what I have tried so far is to get the separated changed values:

```
awk -F '[||]+' 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR,i]=$i;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[FNR,i]!=$i)print $i"#"a[FNR,i]}' file1 file2 >output
```

But I want to print the whole line. How can I achieve that??

Comment: it is a bit unclear what you pretend. Also, it is worth indicating what did you try.

Comment: sure let me update my answer

Comment: so you are just comparing the common lines? that is, line 1 on file1 with line 1 on file2, etc.

Comment: yes, can u please help me how to do it...

Comment: What is this behaviour? I answer your question, you accept it and then just unaccept with any kind of explanation. If you have a new question, ask a new question. If you weren't consistent in your requirements, specify so and provide some feedback.

Comment: i'm extremly sorry.. i'm now to stackoverflow.. even though i asked a couple of questions .. i guess by mistake the answer got unchecked..

Comment: @fedorqui can u please review the changed required?

Comment: I don't understand what is the logic you expect here. How can I know if a line is "new"? Is there any specific pattern to reflect that? How do you "explain" it in an algorithmic way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78091/discussion-between-bongboy-and-fedorqui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     FNR==NR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) a[FNR,i]=$i; next}
     {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2)
         if (a[FNR,i] && a[FNR,i]!=$i)
             $i=$i"#"a[FNR,i]
     }1' f1 f2
```

This stores the file1 in a matrix `a[line number, column]`. Then, it compares its values with its correspondence in file2.

Note I am using the field separator `|` instead of `||` and looping in steps of two to use the proper data. This is because I for example did `gawk -F'||' '{print NF}' f1` and got just `1`, meaning that `FS` wasn't well understood. Will be grateful if someone points the error here!

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) a[FNR,i]=$i; next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) if (a[FNR,i] && a[FNR,i]!=$i) $i=$i"#"a[FNR,i]}1' f1 f2
a||d||f||b#a
1||1#2||3||4
1||2||r||f
```